# Scala setters - multiple parameters

Tags: scala, parameters, setter

Can I use multiple parameters in setters?

For example:

```
private var _a = 0
def a = _a
def a_= (b: Int, c: Int) = _a = b + c
```

If yes, how can I call the setter method?

Comment: Tuples are good. Also consider using method `update()`, e.g. `def update(p1: T1, p2: T2, p3: T3, v: V)` then you can write `obj(p1, p2, p3) = v`

Comment: And yes, you still can call it `obj.a_=(1, 2)` but probably it isn't a 'setter' ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about a tuple?

```
class A {
  private var _a = 0
  def a = _a
  def a_= (t: (Int, Int)) {
    _a = t._1 + t._2
  }
}
```

If you don't like awkward tuple access syntax:

```
class A {
  private var _a = 0
  def a = _a
  def a_= (t: (Int, Int)) {
    t match {
      case(b, c) => _a = b + c
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val x = new A()
x.a = (3, 7)
x.a  //10
```

Comment: Example of how this is called? (I've never been able to get this to work nicely... at least in [the now old] 2.8.)

Comment: @Tomasz: Thanks, I forgot tuple. However, sometimes I get confused because a name is better than `_1`, `_2`... But tuple is better than a map with keys... :-)

Comment: @haibison: I updated my answer to reflect your concerns about confusing tuple syntax, maybe you'll find the second version better.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set single value from two other values it is probably not a 'setter'. Consider giving this operation a meaningful name or moving it out of this class.

```
private var _s: Whatever = // init 
def s_=(newValue: Whatever): Unit = _setter = newValue
...
implicit def t2whatever(t: (SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB)): Whatever = // some logic here
```

now we cal call our setter

```
obj.setter = sta -> stb
// or
obj.setter = (sta, stb)
```

Which is more or less the same as with plain tuples however, setter semantic isn't mangled.

In case its internal operations in may look like:

```
class Z {
  private var _s = // init

  def s = _s
  def s_=(newValue: S) = _s = newValue
}

object Z {
  def toS(a: S, b: S): S = ChineseZodiac.choose(0.14 * a, math.PI + b)
}
```

and then

```
obj.s = Z.toS(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that setter semantic could be changed, but sometimes I use that setter in a tiny of code, and it seems to be easier if I don't split that code into another object or class...